# No me ejecuta bien un script de alert en php

Tags: php, javascript, php7, script

Mi problema es que estoy creando app la cual añade eventos en un calendario. Mi intencion es que cuando añade un evento salga un alert conforme se ha añadido correctamente.

En mi `php` a la hora de añadir el evento le he puesto que salga el alert con un script como podeis ver a continuacion:

```
if ($INS_event->execute()) {
      echo '<script>Swal.fire({
                type: "success",
                title: "Se ha añadido un evento!"
              })</script>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<script>Swal.fire({
                type: "error",
                title: "Oops...",
                text: "Algo ha ido mal!"
              })</script>';
    }
```

No os pongo todo el codigo `php` porque lo que es añadir la actividad me lo hace correctamente el problema lo tengo al final que no me ejecuta el script para que aparezca el alert. La cosa es que si pongo un texto normal en el `php` este lo muestra en pantalla correctamente pero el script no me lo ejecuta. La forma correcta que muestra el mensaje es este:

```
if ($INS_event->execute()) {
      echo 'Nueva actividad añadida';
    }
    else {
      echo 'Lo siento no se añadio';
    }
```

Espero que tengais alguna respuesta. Gracias!

Codigo `php`:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  include 'database.php';

  $id_attivita = $_POST["id_attivita"];
  $commessa = $_POST["commessa"];
  $scuola = $_POST["scuola"];
  $attivita = $_POST["attivita"];
  $title = $_POST["title"];
  $desde = $_POST["desde"];
  $hasta = $_POST["hasta"];
  $data = $_POST["data"];
  $inizio = $_POST["inizio"];
  $start = $_POST["start"];
  $fine = $_POST["fine"];
  $end = $_POST["end"];
  $duration = $_POST["duration"];
  $directa = $_POST["directa"];
  $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];

  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 

    if (isset($_SESSION['matricolo'])) {
        if ($_SESSION['matricolo'] == NULL) {
          $codice_Fiscale_user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        }
        else {
          $codice_Fiscale_user = $_SESSION['matricolo'];
        }
    }

    else {
      $codice_Fiscale_user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    }

  }

  $repeticion = $_POST['repeticion'];

  if(!empty($id_attivita) && !empty($commessa) && !empty($scuola) && !empty($attivita) && !empty($title) && !empty($data) && !empty($inizio) && !empty($start) && !empty($fine) && !empty($end) && !empty($duration) && !empty($directa) && !empty($codice_Fiscale_user)){

    $serachActivADD = $conn->prepare('SELECT id_vitaever FROM attivita WHERE id_attivita = :id_attivita');
    $serachActivADD->bindParam(':id_attivita', $id_attivita);
    $serachActivADD->execute();
    $activArrayADD = $serachActivADD->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $activitatADD = null;

    if (count($activArrayADD) > 0) {
      $activitatADD = $activArrayADD;
    }

    $serachEventADD = $conn->prepare('SELECT id_vitaever FROM operatore WHERE codice_Fiscale = :codice_Fiscale');
    $serachEventADD->bindParam(':codice_Fiscale', $codice_Fiscale_user);
    $serachEventADD->execute();
    $eventArrayADD = $serachEventADD->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $eventADD = null;

    if (count($eventArrayADD) > 0) {
      $eventADD = $eventArrayADD;
    }

    $query_INS = "INSERT INTO evento (id_attivita, commessa, scuola, attivita, desde, hasta, title, start, end, data, inizio, fine, repeticion, duration, directa, descripcion, id_vitaever_Attiv, id_vitaever_Oper, backgroundColor, borderColor, codice_Fiscale_user) VALUES (:id_attivita, :commessa, :scuola, :attivita, :desde, :hasta, :title, :start, :end, :data, :inizio, :fine, :repeticion, :duration, :directa, :descripcion, :id_vitaever_Attiv, :id_vitaever_Oper, :backgroundColor, :borderColor, :codice_Fiscale_user)";

    $INS_event = $conn->prepare($query_INS);

    $INS_event->bindParam(':id_attivita', $id_attivita);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':commessa', $commessa);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':scuola', $scuola);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':attivita', $attivita);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':desde', $desde);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':hasta', $hasta);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':start', $start);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':end', $end);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':data', $data);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':inizio', $inizio);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':fine', $fine);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':repeticion', $repeticion);  
    $INS_event->bindParam(':duration', $duration);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':directa', $directa);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':descripcion', $descripcion);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':id_vitaever_Attiv', $activitatADD['id_vitaever']);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':id_vitaever_Oper', $eventADD['id_vitaever']);

    if($directa == 1){  
      $backgroundColor ='#D0EC61';
      $borderColor = '#D0EC61';
    }

    else{
      $backgroundColor = '#F6CF4E';
      $borderColor = '#F6CF4E';
    }

    $INS_event->bindParam(':backgroundColor', $backgroundColor);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':borderColor', $borderColor);
    $INS_event->bindParam(':codice_Fiscale_user', $codice_Fiscale_user);

    if ($INS_event->execute()) { 
      echo '<script>Swal.fire({ 
        type: '. "success".', 
        title: '."Se ha añadido un evento!".' 
      })</script>'; 
    } else { 
      echo '<script>Swal.fire({ 
        type: '."error".', 
        title: '."Oops...".', 
        text: '."Algo ha ido mal!".' 
      })</script>'; 
    }
  }

  else {
    echo 'Completa los campos';
  }

?>
```

Comment: El problema tal vez sea el lugar en el que colocas el código en tu pagina, imagino que llamas a una librería js para el alert, intenta colocar ese código php debajo del código con el que llamas la librería.

Comment: El alert que introduzco es una llamada a ajax.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes usar **JS** desde **PHP** de la manera que estás haciendo. Cuando pintes ese `<script>` desde **PHP** el navegador no lo va a ejecutar porque el **DOM** ya ha cargado.

Pero dado que estás usando **AJAX** tienes una sencilla solución. En vez de tratar de lanzar el `alert` desde **PHP** que tu `.php` retorne un mensaje y si el mensaje es el que quieres entonces desde el **response** de tu llamada AJAX es cuando ejecutas el `alert`.

**EJEMPLO de llamada AJAX con JQuery**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urldetuphp.php,
    cache: false,
    success: function (respuesta) {
        if (respuesta == 'success') {
            Swal.fire({
                type: "success",
                title: "Se ha añadido un evento!"
            })
        }
        else {
           if (respuesta == 'error') {
               Swal.fire({
                type: "error",
                title: "Oops...",
                text: "Algo ha ido mal!"
              })
           }
    }
});
```

**EJEMPLO de PHP llamado desde AJAX**

```
if ($INS_event->execute()) {
    echo 'success';
}
else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: Gracias hoy no me va a dar tiempo pero mañana a primera hora lo intentare tine buena pinta, Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Asegurate de tener en tu `<head>  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>`

He utilizado Sweet Alert antes y la syntax parece correcta.

Otro problema podrían ser las comillas simples que tienes al inicio del echo, te recomendaría tratar de concatenar las comillas dobles que tienes en el interior del echo, también he tenido algunos problemas utilizando comillas dobles dentro de echo.

Espero te sea de utilidad, Saludos.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme, de todas formas muchas gracias!

Comment: Seguro probaste  `if ($INS_event->execute()) {
      echo '<script>Swal.fire({
                type: '. "success".',
                title: '."Se ha añadido un evento!".'
              })</script>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<script>Swal.fire({
                type: '."error".',
                title: '."Oops...".',
                text: '."Algo ha ido mal!".'
              })</script>';
    }`

A mi me a funcionado

Comment: Podrías editar la pregunta con el código de todo el archivo, obviamente eliminando lo que no puedes mostrar públicamente o no quieras mostrar, solo para ver como esta estructurado, a ver si puedo ayudarte.

Comment: He utilizado lo que has puesto en el otro comentario y no funciona ahora pongo el codigo php completo.

Comment: El html que utiliza tu php tiene instalado SweetAlert2? [Trata de ver esta documentación](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download), esto es lo ultimo que se me ocurre que pueda pasar.

Comment: Por ejemplo yo lo utilice para ver en que posición (longitud y latitud) estaba dando click:

       `Swal.fire({ 
            title: "Position",
            text: "En el puerto PSA",
            type: "info",
   
        });
        }else if(longitudeString== -79.56 && latitudeString== 8.96){
        Swal.fire({ 
            title: "Position",
            text: "En el puerto Balboa",
            type: "info",
        });
        }else{
            Swal.fire({ 
            title: "Position",
            text: totaldegree,
            type: "info" 
        });`

Comment: Sisi el php coge los documentos del SweetAlert2 que estan en una carpeta.

Comment: Pero yo no lo tengo en un php así que no lo tengo que concatenar, podrías comentar el error que te tira la herramienta de desarrollo del chrome